# Error when registering an event listener, using Spring Security Core plugin & Grails 2.0.0

Tags: events, authentication, grails, groovy, spring-security

Im trying to register an event listener for a successful login, so that I can perform some logic when i know a user has just authenticated. As per the spring security docs, im registering the event as follows:

```
package grails.admin

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener
import org.springframework.security.authentication.event. AuthenticationSuccessEvent

class SuccessfulAuthenticationEventListener implements ApplicationListener<AuthenticationSuccessEvent> {

    void onApplicationEvent(AuthenticationSuccessEvent event){
        System.out.println("THERE WAS A SUCCESSFUL LOGIN");
    }

}
```

And then wiring it up in config.groovy as follows:

```
import grails.admin.SuccessfulAuthenticationEventListener
beans = {
    successfulAuthenticationEventListener(SuccessfulAuthenticationEventListener)
}
```

When I run my project, it crashes out with the following message:

```
[Thread-9] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error executing bootstraps: Cannot cast object 'Config$_run_closure5@4eff1d61' with class 'Config$_run_closure5' to class 'groovy.util.ConfigObject'
```

Ive googled the error with no luck, and now turn to you wonderful people! Is there just a problem with compatibility and I'm gonna have to use a different method of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

resources.groovy is used for registering additional spring beans. You have to put the bean definition in resources.groovy and not config.groovy

Answer (score 2):

You should add following property in Config.groovy

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.useSecurityEventListener = true
```

And register listener in resources.groovy

```
beans = {
    mySecurityEventListener(com.abc.MySecurityEventListener)
```

}

http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/7%20Events.html